# Tableview methods are never called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an iOS app where I added a `UITableView` to my view in Interface Builder. Then I set up the tableview in the `UIViewController` like this:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 25, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

And I also implemented the following methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("test table")
    let course = self.courses[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CourseTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CourseTableViewCell

    cell.make(course, location: self.currentLocation)

    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return courses.count
}
```

However, the methods are never called, the table view isn't being displayed and I get no errors in my console? Is there something I missed while trying to add this?

Thanks.

As per request in the comments:

- The `courses` array is not empty
- The `courses` array is being filled before `reloadData()`

Comment: did you have linked the TableView to the code as IBOutlet?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes, it's linked: `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

Comment: Where do you call `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: @vadian It's being called in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Is `courses` empty?

Comment: Please add more information. How, where and **when** is the data source array being populated?

Comment: @Larme It's not. It's being filled before the `reloadData()` call

Comment: @vadian Updated the Question

Comment: What's the frame of your tableView?

Comment: @Larme I didn't define the frame, It's done in Interface Builder. However, the constrains you'd need are all set

Comment: *array is being filled before reloadData()*. Are you sure? Many people use asynchronous API calls and put the `reloadData()` call *physically* after the method call which is not the same as *temporarily* in this case.

Comment: @vadian I'm sure of that. The method is not being called until the results are in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead of your code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!{
    didSet {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Make sure your controller is conforming to the two protocols: `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Then add this method to make sure that your cells do not have 0 pts height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80 // adjust height of row as needed 
}
```

Comment: A property observer for an outlet is not a good suggestion. The most suitable way is to connect data source and delegate in Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

just try to implements "heightForRowAtIndexPath"
I think your table is properly reloaded but due to constraints in cell
UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not working.
2 - make sure courses is properly allocated, use Debugger in numberOfRowsAtIndexPath to check items in courses

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the delegate methods are executed by setting a breakpoint in a method like numberOfSections or numberOfRowsInSection.

When the breakpoint doesn't get hit the delegates are not set properly.

Comment: What is the count/length of the courses inside the numberOfRows method ?